# Listing ancestors and descendents of process ID

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process, parent

I'm creating a program that takes a Process ID and lists its name as we as network connections.

```
echo '==========================='
echo 'please enter a process ID: '
read pidN
ps -p $pidN|awk '{print $1, $4}'
echo '==========================='
echo 'here are the network connections for: ' $pidN
sudo netstat -p|grep $pidN

echo '==========================='
echo 'The Parent Process ID: '
ps -p ${pidN:-$$} -o ppid=
```

the next step is to take that ID entered by the user and find 3 parent processes of that ID and 3 child processes of that ID.

I presume i need to create a for loop to recursively get the parents and child processes however I'm not sure how this will be done.

Can anyone direct me towards where i should start or how it would be done.

Many thanks!

Comment: Look at `pstree`

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  Nevertheless, this `perl` snippet should get you started.  `ps -ef | perl -e 'while(<>){ @p = split; $ppid{$p[1]} = $p[2];} for $i (sort(keys(%ppid))) { for($i; int($i) > 0; $i = $ppid{$i}) { print "$i => "; } print "\n"; }'`.  This probably won't work on all systems, but I tested it on Ubuntu 17.04 and Solaris 7.  And it's a comment because it doesn't answer the question.